# How to loop tooptip additional data in chart.js

Tags: jquery, graph, chart.js

Here i have a graph which contains x-axis data and y-axis data which are com from db table. and now i am facing a problem is that, wherever i trying to append this 3rd data in `afterbody` callback function in tooltip. it will shows entire data in each and every tool tip.

But i want to append these data in each tool tip respectively.

**like:**

on 1st tool tip **margin 12%**

on 2nd tool tip **margin 5%**

on 3rd tool tip **margin 25%** and so on.

**Here is a screen shot from current graph with tool tip data**

[image]

**And here is my code**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php base_url();?>/charts/getsome",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            var month = [];
            var customers = [];
            var margin = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                month.push("Customer in " + data[i].apply_month);
                customers.push(data[i].no_customers);
                margin.push(data[i].margin);
            }
            var chartdata = {
                labels: month,              
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'monthly customers for Year 2016',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: customers,
                        fill: false
                    }

                ]

            };

            var frame = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(frame, {
                type: 'line',               
                data: chartdata,
                options: {
                          responsive: true,
                          tooltips: {
                             callbacks: {
                                afterBody: function(t, d) {
                                   return 'margin  '+margin;
                                }
                             }
                          }
                       }
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Now i just want to showing these margin percentage data separately for each tool tip. Please suggest me, where i am going wrong? Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your tooltip­*'s* `afterBody` callback function ...

**ꜰʀᴏᴍ ᴛʜɪꜱ**

```
tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
      afterBody: function(t, d) {
         return 'margin  ' + margin;
      }
   }
}
```

**ᴛᴏ ᴛʜɪꜱ**

```
tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
      afterBody: function(t, d) {
         return 'margin ' + margin[t[0].index];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: where t . index come from?